# Transferring money from Indian NRE account to UK

Tags: united-kingdom, india, non-resident, money-transfer

I am an Indian citizen with permanent resident status in the UK and I need to get some money from India to UK to purchase a property. My father will be gifting me the money and he has the money in his NRE account (he is an NRI). Is there any tax to be paid for this?

More specifically, my father has the NRE account in State Bank group and I have an NRE account in SBI (if that makes things easier).

Answer (score 1):

From an Indian tax point of view, this transaction is not taxable to you or your father.