# Money Repatriation from India to UK

Tags: united-kingdom, india, transfer

One question on money repatriation, if I bring money from India to UK. What is the tax implication in UK. If money is coming for

1. Money is repatriated from NRE account
2. Money is repatriated from NRO account

Comment: Related but different [What tax implications are there in India?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/46449/25282)  Also, [Remittance of gift money from my Indian bank account to UK bank account](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/53770/25282) is similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Money in your NRE/NRO account is *your* property and moving it to the U.K. is not a taxable event in the U.K. or in India. Extra paperwork is needed for transfer from an NRO account to prove that you have indeed paid taxes (or had taxes withheld) on the money in the NRO account to the Indian Government. Search this site for "15CB" and "15CA" for details.